Is there a way to automatically set the label to caption of a figure / table?
I use a lot of figures and tables in each document a write for my studies. After a while it gets pretty cumbersome to always write both the caption and the label seperately.
Since most of my captions are pretty short and I work in many small documents, I'd like to find a solution such that all captions I write are also automatically set as a label to the corresponding figure / table and I can reference the object just by typing \ref{"caption"} (preferably the label is actually set to fig: "caption" or tab: "caption" to keep track of what label actually corresponds to what object).
A MWE would be something like
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{x.png}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \label{fig: Lorem ipsum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

where the line \label{fig: Lorem ipsum} is automatically generated by the program itself just by typing \begin{figure} (I use Overleaf) or is just somehow saved in the background while not being displayed in the actual code.
Is there a way to implement this?

you shouldn't do that. If you later think that Lorem ipsum is not correct and should have been ipsum lorem or Lorem Ipsum your label will change and all references will fail. The label key should be independant of the caption text.

you obviously could define a macro say \foo{Lorem} defined as \newcommand\foo[1]{\caption{#1}\label{fig:#1}} and use that instead of separate \caption and \label but in general it is not advisable. The point of \label is an internal identifier that is stable if you edit the caption or change the figure order, you do not have to find all \ref in the document and edit them.

@UlrikeFischer ooh you were a few seconds faster

And don't ignore the comments to the linked question …
